# Beginner Module Pattern JavaScript - Parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, module, module-pattern

I'm just getting started on the Module Pattern in JavaScript with [this](https://carldanley.com/js-module-pattern/) article.

I'm not understanding why there's 2 parameters in the first line but only 1 argument is being passed in at the very end, `window`.

```
(function(window, undefined) {
  //some code
})(window);
```

Why is `undefined` a parameter and where is it coming from?

Comment: it's an old "optimization" pattern anyway, don't worry about it, but know that any formal parameter without an argument passed will be `undefined` inside.

Comment: This explains it https://toddmotto.com/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means/